# PLSQL -- calling function to calculate with char(1) and number variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm just now teaching myself SQL and PLSQL and have haven't had too much trouble debugging the regular SQL, but I'm trying to call a PLSQL function that is throwing errors that I can't figure out from the Oracle docs and other online resources.  I'm using Oracle SQL-Developer.
I've tried these but they are not helpful in this case:

[How to return a record from an existing table from an Oracle PL/SQL function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336743/how-to-return-a-record-from-an-existing-table-from-an-oracle-pl-sql-function?rq=1)

[Writing a function in plsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267533/writing-a-function-in-plsql)

[Oracle PLSQL function call into a second function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550574/oracle-plsql-function-call-into-a-second-function)

[Can't seem to subract two numbers in a PLSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045128/cant-seem-to-subract-two-numbers-in-a-plsql-function)

I've tried writing the same function 2 different ways for practice:

```
Create Function Calc_Tax
(Quantity IN Number,Unit_Price IN Number,Taxable IN VarChar2)
    Return Number IS amt Number;
Declare
price := Quantity * Unit_Price;
Begin
    IF Taxable = 'Y' THEN
    amt := price + 0.06 * price;
  ELSE
    amt := price;
  END IF;
  Return amt;
End;

-- or --

Create Or Replace Function Calc_Tax
(Quantity IN Number,Unit_Price IN Number,tax IN Sale_Item.Taxable%TYPE)
    Return Number IS amt Number;
  Declare
  price := Quantity * Unit_Price;
  Begin
    IF tax = 'Y' THEN
    amt := price + 0.06 * price;
  ELSE
    amt := price;
  END IF;
  Return amt;
End;
```

I had some trouble declaring the 'tax' parameter as a varchar2(1) so I left it just varchar2 which the docs seem to say is default for 1 space (if I read that right).  Of course, I'd rather do it properly and declare the size of the varchar explicitly.

This is how I'm calling it:

```
DECLARE
   g_last Guest.First_Name%type := 'Richard';
   g_last Guest.Last_Name%type := 'Wharton';
   g_id Guest.Guest_ID%type;
   s_g_id Stay.Guest_ID%type;
   sho_id Stay.Hotel_ID%type;
   h_id Hotel.Hotel_ID%type;
   h_name  Hotel.Hotel_Name%type;
   i_id Sale_Item.Item_ID%type;
   i_name  Sale_Item.Item_Name%type;
   i_tax  Sale_Item.Taxable%type;
   cs_id Charge.Stay_ID%type;
   c_date Charge.Trans_Date%type;
   c_quant Charge.Quantity%type;
   c_uprice Charge.Unit_Price%type;
BEGIN
   SELECT H.Hotel_ID, H.Hotel_Name,C.Item_ID, Item_Name, C.Trans_Date, C.Quantity, 
   C.Unit_Price,Taxable INTO h_id,h_name,i_id,i_name,c_date,c_quant,c_uprice
   FROM Hotel H,Charge C Where cs_id = (Select Stay_ID From Stay Where Guest_ID = 
   (Select Guest_ID From Guest Where First_Name='Richard' And Last_Name='Wharton'));
   --WHERE id = c_id;

   dbms_output.put_line
   ('Guest ' ||g_first || g_last || ' bought ' || i_name || ' with tax ' || Calc_Tax

(c_quant,c_uprice,i_tax));
END;
```

And it's throwing errors:

```
Error(18,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" 
Error(43,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge
```

Here's the schema:

[image]

I'm just learning now, so I'm sure that any junior SQL programmers can quickly show me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: DECLARE is a sql*plus command, not a PL/SQL keyword. The links you reference show an example of a simple functio that has the correct syntax.

Comment: @OldProgrammer DECLARE is PL/SQL's !

Comment: @OldProgrammer - `DECLARE` isn't an SQL*Plus command, it's part of [the PL/SQL block](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#i8859). You can use it as part of an anoymous block from anywhere, and as part of a trigger declaration. But it isn't valid for a function declaration, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use DECLARE inside a procedure or function -- use the `AS` keyword instead to indicate the variable declaration "block."

You also cannot put a constraint on parameters (e.g. you can have `VARCHAR2` but not `VARCHAR2(10)` -- [See Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/parameter_declaration.htm#LNPLS1574)

You also shouldn't have a semi-colon following your return statement.

```
Create Function Calc_Tax (Quantity IN Number, Unit_Price IN Number, Taxable IN VarChar2) 
Return Number
AS
  My_Variable VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
    -- code
END Calc_Tax;
```

Comment: Adding to your answer, INTO part is missing a variable (taxable) as well! And also worth mentioning. If SELECT returns more than one row, we need to loop it as a implicit/explicit cursor.

Answer (score 1):

In the SELECT part you selects 8 columns, after the INTO you would like to store it into 7 variables:

```
SELECT 
  H.Hotel_ID, 
  H.Hotel_Name,
  C.Item_ID, 
  Item_Name, 
  C.Trans_Date, 
  C.Quantity, 
  C.Unit_Price,
  Taxable 
 INTO 
   h_id,
   h_name,
   i_id,
   i_name,
   c_date,
   c_quant,
   c_uprice
```

The i_tax variable is missing.